# How do you specify which datatable to destroy?

Tags: angular, datatables

I have two datatables in an Angular view, and on a button press I am trying to destroy and re-populate one of the tables. However my code is destroying both, how do I specify which table to destroy? This is [the documentation](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender) I've been using

**On button press**

```
  searchByCoid(term: string): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {dtInstance.destroy();});
    this.getUsersByCoid(term.trim()); //repopulate the table with different data
  }
```

**HTML that creates tables**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptionsComp" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerCompany" class="row-border hover">
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let d of companylist" (click)="selectCompany($event, d)" [class.highlighted]="d.highlighted">
    <td>{{d.id}}</td><td>{{d.name}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>

<h1>Select User to Modify</h1>
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptionsUser" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerUser" class="row-border hover">
    <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Company ID</th><th>User ID</th><th>PAIOS Acct ID</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let c of userlist">
    <td>{{c.firstname}}</td><td>{{c.lastname}}</td><td>{{c.companyId}}</td><td>{{c.user_id}}</td><td>{{c.PAIOS_acctid}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can't you define your table as a reference? for example `<table #dt1>` then on your `typescript` you would do `@ViewChild('dt1') dt1: DataTableDirective;`

Comment: Tried that, returned undefined. Thanks for the suggestion though!